# How can I take out genera names of my column name from data frame in R? There is a function for this?

Tags: r

Here is my df:

```
Accepted_name            latitude    longitude    counts
Abarema                  -24.646667   -48.39194      1
Abutavelutina            -22.773333   -45.56250      1
Abutilon                 -20.810000   -49.38056      1
Abutilon abutiloides     -14.218333   -47.90278      1
Abutilon affine          -23.650000   -46.61667      1
Abutilon amoenum         -22.808611   -44.36306      1
```

I want to take out only genera names of my column Accepted_name.

Comment: What are the genera names? Everything up to the first space, if any?

Comment: My generas is: Abarema; Abutavelutina; Abutilon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
gsub(" .*", "", df$Accepted_name)
```